# AWS issue with django backend and vue js frontend

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

my django backend is deployed on aws elastic beanstalk on default settings and auto scaling env type is single instance
vue js frontend is hosted on aws s3, its setting is done with cloudfront and its now running on https from subdomain

my backend is still on http and works fine on http and i have configured a https subdomain with ssl certificate, but when i add it to elastic beanstalk, elastic beanstalk gets severe health and stops gives this
"100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (6.0 requests/min) to determine application health."

my rds is postgresql and handled separately, by just connecting it on django settings.

I want to do rest api calls from aws s3 to elastic beanstalk

it would be helpful, if you also specify django cors settings and frontend axios api call settings for such stack

i tried with http back and front end and its working,

I want to do rest api calls from aws s3 to elastic beanstalk backend
both on https

it would be helpful, if you also specify django cors settings and frontend axios api call settings for such stack

thanks

Comment: No details, no code, no logs, blobs of text. This question is likely unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

u means 'severe health and stops gives this "cpu 100.0 %' is problem??

i think u have to handle 'max connection' at gunicorn or uwsgi

if u want more information, u have to write your code.